# Python: Get list of integers by reference from list of objects - Python

Tags: python, list, reference, integer, pass-by-reference

I have 2D list (matrix) of objects with one attribute as an integer (or float).
I need to perform some operations on the matrix of these integer attributes in the way, that the objects in first list will change as well.
But when I make an 2D list of those attributes, they are not copied by the reference. Therefore changing this list of integers will make no change to list of objects.

Is there some simple way to pass these integers to my list by reference?
I don't want to always compute the list and rewrite all the object attributes, as it is too time-consuming.

Code for example:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value

list_of_objects = []
list_of_values = []
for i in range (2):
    list_of_objects.append([])
    list_of_values.append([])
    for j in range(2):
         item = A(2)
         list_of_objects[i].append(item)
         list_of_values[i].append(item.value)

print (list_of_values) # getting [[2,2],[2,2]]
list_of_values[1][1] *= 3
print (list_of_objects[1][1].value) # getting 2, want 6
```

This is just simle example. In fact the thing that I want to do is matrix convolution

Comment: "pass by reference" is not the right terminology here. In any case, *references to the `int`'s are what go in to `list_of_values`*. But `int` and `float` objects **are immutable**. You **cannot change their value**.

Comment: What "operations on the matrix of these integer attributes" and why can't you instead do the operations on the matrix of objects?

Comment: Just use one list. Make up your mind which of the two you *really* want to have and work with that.